# How to Get a Single Data Form Firebase With out Using strembuilder or futurebuilder In Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how can i Get this single data "key" with out using strembuilder or futurebuilder...In flutter Using FireBase
I just wanna check if my master password  == key
Any help??

[image]

Comment: yes, https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#documentsnapshot will help you in doing so. Get the `DocumentSnapShot` of the whole collection. then check if the password matches the document key in the collection using `foreach`. If you know the document id then you can directly use a QuerrySnapshot https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querysnapshot

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('/admin')
              .get()
              .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
              var id = doc["key"];
            });
          });  if (masterkey != id) {
            return;
          } How can i access the id now.?? can you tell pls

Comment: wait ill write an answer

Answer (score 3):

```
final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('admin/6Ctki5kFhlcycvim7Mar').get();
final hashResult = result.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
final password = hashResult['key'];
```

You can get password value with the above code snippet.

Comment: The method 'data' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'data'    Why Iam Getting this Error...can you please tell??

Comment: change final result to final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> result

Comment: A value of type 'Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' now getting this Error...pls help

Comment: @mdrafsan Are you sure you added the **'await'** statement? ('final result = **await** ..')

Comment: Sorry My bad...I carelessly removed it now its working fine...Thanks a lot. It helped a Lot

Answer (score 1):

### The steps are as follows:

hope `Firebase.initializeApp();` has been called before executing the below steps.
All the below steps can be written in a separate `class` or the `WidetNameState extends State<WidgetName>{}` class where you are using the firestore data.

**Step 1:** Create the Firestore instance.

`FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;`

**Step 2:** Creating a Function that gets all the documents as a list from the collection:

```
///This function Returns the Collection Documents as a List.
///
/// Parameter [collection] takes the name of the collection to be queried.
Future<List<QueryDocumentSnapshot>> getCollectionDocumentsAsList(String collection) async {
    final QuerySnapshot data = await _firestore.collection('$collection').get();
    return data.docs;
  }
```

**Step 4:** Checking the "key" from each document matches your "master password or not":

```
/// pass your master password to [masterPassword]
  void checkPassword(String masterPassword)async{
    /// this variable will contain the document from firestore that has the same key as your master password.
    DocumentSnapshot passwordMatchDoc;
    
    // admin is the collection name.
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documents = await getCollectionDocumentsAsList('admin');
    
    documents.forEach((DocumentSnapshot doc){
      if (doc["key"] == masterPassword){
        passwordMatchDoc = doc;
      }
    });
  }
```

Here you can also use a `for` loop instead of `.forEach((d){})` and `break` when the password matches. Or declare the variable out of the function and then store the document that has the same password as the master password there.

you can call the `checkPassword('masterPassword')` in the `initState(){}` function of the widget class.

---

A small tip, since the document id in the firestore collection looks like being auto-generated so at the time of app execution there is no way to know the actual id of the document, hence you would have to loop all over the documents and check for the `key` field of each document with your password.
But in future, if you know the document id of the particular key you want you can use the below function which returns all the fields in the document as a `DocumentSnapshot` and will reduce your compute time.

```
/// Returns a [DocumentSnapshot] of [document] from [collection] specified.
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getCollectionDocument(String collection, String document) async => await _firestore.collection(collection).doc(document).get();
```